# How to sort a array that contains special characters alphabetically?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I am looking for code that produces the following output in standard output from the following string prepared according to a certain format.

Assumptions and rules:

- Each letter is used 2 times in the given string and the letters between the same 2 letters are to be considered *child* letters.
- The given string is always given in proper format. The string format
  does not need to be checked.

#### Example:

**Input** : `abccbdeeda`

**Expected output**:

```
a
--b
----c
--d
----e
```

**Explanation:** since the 2 letters "b" occur between the letters "a", the letter b takes 2 hyphens (`--b`)

#### Attempt

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "abccbdeeda";
    System.out.println("input: " + input);
    String[] strSplit = input.split("");
    String g = "";
    String h = "-";

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    int counter = 1;
    boolean secondNumber;
    list.add(strSplit[0]);
    int dual = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < strSplit.length; i++) {
        secondNumber = list.contains(strSplit[i]);
        if ((secondNumber)) {
            counter--;
            dual = counter * 2;
            for (int f = 0; f < dual; f++) {
                strSplit[i] = h.concat(strSplit[i]);
            }
            g = "";
            dual = 0;
        } else {
            list.add(strSplit[i]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    Arrays.sort(strSplit);
    for (int p = 0; p < strSplit.length; p++) {
        System.out.println(strSplit[p]);
    }
}
```

**input:** `abccbdeeda`

**My output:**

```
----c 
----e 
--b 
--d 
a
```

I wasn't able to sort the output alphabetically. How can I sort alphabetically with those hyphen characters in them?

Comment: Can you please explain the input and output in detail?

Comment: Can you explain how the requirements state that the output must be ordered alphabetically?  What would the correct output be for "fbccbdeedf"?   And why?

Comment: output : --b ----c --d ----e  f. The output would be like this. @StephenC

Comment: Why?  Please explain where in the requirements that it states that.

Comment: If it is between 2 letters, a hyphen is added. (-). @StephenC

Comment: 1)  There are no numbers.  Only letters.  2) That says nothing about the order of output.  Either you have misinterpreted the instructions ... or you have not completely and accurately stated them in the Question.

Comment: Or put it another way, why is "f --b ----c --d ----e" not a correct answer too?

Answer (score 0):

This task is nicely done with the help of a stack. If the current character is equal to the top of the stack, then the character is closed and can be removed, otherwise we met it for the first time and it must be added to the stack and the resulting string by adding before it `stack.size() * 2` dashes.

When we have completely traversed the string we can sort the resulting string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    String string = "abccbdeeda";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        char curChar = string.charAt(i);
        if(!stack.isEmpty() && curChar == stack.peek()) {
            stack.pop();
        } else {
            result.append("-".repeat(stack.size() * 2)).append(curChar).append(" ");
            stack.add(curChar);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(result.toString().split(" ")).sorted().toArray()));
}
```

Output

```
a --b ----c --d ----e 
[----c, ----e, --b, --d, a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the strSplit array and extract the charactors in each element to a separate list/array. To check whether the array element contains a letter you can write a regular expression.
Ex:     `private final Pattern x = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");`

Write a separate method to match the patern to each element in the strSplit array. This method will return the charactor in your input string.

```
private String findCharactor(final StringBuilder element) {
        final Matcher matcher = x.matcher(element);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            final int matchIndex = matcher.start(); //this gives the index of the char in the string
            return element.substring(matchIndex); 
        }
}
```

Add these returned charactors to a separate array and sort it using sorting function.

Comment: Yea ... but while this answers the question asked ... I'm pretty sure that a better solution to the problem does not entail sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your result list is:

```
List<String> resultList = Arrays.asList("----c", "----e", "--b", "--d", "a");
```

You can sort it alphabetically by a single line:

```
Collections.sort(resultList, (o1, o2) -> new StringBuilder(o1).reverse().toString().compareTo(new StringBuilder(o2).reverse().toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion for a depth-first traversal (preorder):

```
public static String dfs(String string, String prefix) {
    if (string.length() == 0) return "";
    int i = string.indexOf(string.charAt(0), 1);
    return prefix + string.charAt(0) + "\n"             // current
           + dfs(string.substring(1, i), prefix + "--") // all nested
           + dfs(string.substring(i + 1), prefix);      // all siblings
}
```

Example call:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(dfs("abccbdeeda", ""));
}
```